# Verify existence of object within the local context of a function

Tags: r

How can I check if a variable exists *within the local context of the function*, not the global context? Like this:

```
aabb <- 1
ccdd <- 2
fff <- function () {
    yyzz <- 1
    ccdd <- c(1, 2)
    different.variant.of.exists("yyzz") # should report TRUE
    different.variant.of.exists("ccdd") # should report TRUE
    different.variant.of.exists("aabb") # should report FALSE
}
```

Comment: Try `exists` with `parent.frame`?

Comment: Try this: `fff <- function () {
  yyzz <- 1
  ccdd <- c(1, 2)
  local(exists("yyzz"))

}`? Using `exists` alone seems sufficient though as Ronak suggests.

Comment: @RonakShah, nope! Look at the "aabb" case! That should report FALSE, `exists` would report TRUE.

Comment: @RonakShah I'm getting `TRUE` for all 3 calls `print(exists("aabb"))`, etc. `print(exists("aabb", inherits = FALSE))` gives `FALSE`.

Comment: @NelsonGon dtto; reports TRUE for "aabb" which is undesired.

Comment: @RuiBarradas `inherits = FALSE` does it! Thanks!

Comment: Ok..ignore me. My variable name was `aab` and I was printing `exists(aabb)`. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why @GKi deleted his answer, because that was exactly it (and exactly what @RuiBarradas mentioned!):

Use `exists` with `inherits = FALSE`:

```
aabb <- 1
ccdd <- 2
fff <- function () {
    yyzz <- 1
    ccdd <- c(1, 2)
    c(exists("yyzz", inherits = FALSE) # should report TRUE
    , exists("ccdd", inherits = FALSE) # should report TRUE
    , exists("aabb", inherits = FALSE)) # should report FALSE
}
fff()
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```